# Azure IoT SDK .NET 6 Support?

Tags: azure-iot-hub

According to the documentation (https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/main/supported_platforms.md), the Azure IoT SDK is only officially supported for .NET 5.

But .NET 5 is end of life, so is this accurate? We wish to run the SDK on Linux on .NET 6, but if it is not officially supported, should we instead target .NET 5, even though it is end of life?

Comment: we can update the version from 5 to 6 using this [reference](https://dev.to/moe23/upgrade-net-5-to-net-6-n2c#:~:text=This%20is%20a%20quick%20check%20list%20that%20you,Youtube%201-%20Upgrade%20the%20reference%20in%20csproj%20files)

Comment: Yes, Azure IoT SDK .NET 6 Support.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Azure IoT SDK Supports .NET 6.

- We can Upgrade from .net5 to .net6.
- From the  reference  [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) we can  Upgrade .Net 5 to [.Net 6](https://dev.to/moe23/upgrade-net-5-to-net-6-n2c#:%7E:text=This%20is%20a%20quick%20check%20list%20that%20you,Youtube%201-%20Upgrade%20the%20reference%20in%20csproj%20files)  .

[image]

- Make sure to Download .NET 6.0 Linux, macOS, and [Windows](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0)

  ```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>   </PropertyGroup>
  ```

[image]

- I tried this sample  Azure IoT SDK for .NET  6 [Developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/iot?view=azure-dotnet) .

```cs
    using (var deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, TransportType.Mqtt))
    {
        await SendTelemetryMessage(deviceClient, deviceId);
    }
}

static async Task SendTelemetryMessage(DeviceClient deviceClient, string deviceId)
{
    try
    {
        var telemetryDataPoint = new
        {
            temperature = 25.5,
            humidity = 60.0
        };
        var messageString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(telemetryDataPoint);
        var message = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageString));
        message.Properties.Add("deviceId", deviceId);

        await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
        Console.WriteLine("Message sent: {0}", messageString);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error sending telemetry: {ex.Message}");
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]